# Facebook Android request error : GraphObject is null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

I'm trying to send a simple request with the Android Facebook SDK. Here is my code :

```
Session.openActiveSession( NATIVE_ACTIVTY, true, new Session.StatusCallback() 
{
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
    {
        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() 
        {
            public void onCompleted(Response response)
            {
                if( response.getError() != null)
                {
                    Log.i( "Output", response.toString());
                    // Here i'm checking token, permissions, ...
                }
            }
        };

        Bundle params = new Bundle();

        params.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());
        params.putString("name", name);
        params.putString("caption", caption);
        params.putString("description", description);
        params.putString("link", link);
        params.putString("picture", picture);

        Request request = new Request( session, "me/feed/", params, HttpMethod.POST, callback );
        request.executeAsync();     

        Log.i( "Output", request.toString() );
    }
}
```

But the request fails, and the response is :

```
I/Output(29990): {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: null}, isFromCache:false}
```

With an error

```
I/Output(29990): com.facebook.FacebookException: could not construct request body
```

I have also checked several things :

- permissions are OK;
- access_token is valid (https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={my_token} works fine from my browser)
- the session state is OPENED

I don't understand why it doesn't works, and I really don't know what to do...

Many thanks

Comment: You should be able to call getCause() on the exception to find out the underlying exception, or log the exception (not just the message) to get a stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you for answer me. The exception is null, so unfortunately, it doesnt help me.

Comment: Ok finally it works, i think it was a problem with a wrong package name on the Facebook Apps page. I fixed it yesterday, but the validation seems to be very long...

Comment: Whats the new code? Please, update your code. :)